ONVIF Camera reports no PTZ
I'm dealing with a situation where I have a ONVIF camera that supports PTZ yet nothing will move it. When I run the query via ONVIF Device Manager it reports it doesn't support PTZ yet if I use the QNAP Survellance software it will move it. Is there a way to over ride and ignore the SOAP reporting?

I tried several tools, this tool resolves the issue and let me update the firmware. ONVIF Studio - https://www.wink.co/wink-onvif-studio.php Its not clear why but it seems it was just a mistake by the manufacture like they put the wrong firmware on when they shipped it but now its good.
